# Rolling upgrade from 1.2.19 to 2.0.15

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We have 3 datacenters with 12 cassandra nodes in each. Current Cassandra version is 1.2.19. We want to migrate to Cassandra 2.0.15. We cannot have a full downtime and we need to do a rolling upgrade. As a preliminary check we've done 2 experiments:

### Experiment 1

1. Created a new 2.0.15 node and tried to bootstrap it into the cluster with 10% of token interval of already existing node.
   The node was unable to join the cluster by producing: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds"

```
    CassandraDaemon.java (line 584) Exception encountered during startup
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
            at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1296)
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:457)
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:671)
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:623)
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:515)
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:437)
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:567)
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:656)
```

### Experiment 2

1. Added one 1.2.19 node into the cluster with 10% of token interval of already existing node.
2. When the node was up we stopped it and upgraded to 2.0.15, then started again (minor downtime). This time the node joined the cluster and started serving requests correctly.
3. To check how it behaves under heavier load we tried to move token to cover 15% of a normal node. Unfortunately 
   the move operation has failed with the following exception:

```
    INFO [RMI TCP Connection(1424)-192.168.1.100] 2015-07-10 11:37:05,235 StorageService.java (line 982) MOVING: fetching new ranges and streaming old ranges
     INFO [RMI TCP Connection(1424)-192.168.1.100] 2015-07-10 11:37:05,262 StreamResultFuture.java (line 87) [Stream #fc3f4290-26f7-11e5-9988-afe392008597] Executing streaming plan for Moving
     INFO [RMI TCP Connection(1424)-192.168.1.100] 2015-07-10 11:37:05,262 StreamResultFuture.java (line 91) [Stream #fc3f4290-26f7-11e5-9988-afe392008597] Beginning stream session with /192.168.1.101
     INFO [StreamConnectionEstablisher:1] 2015-07-10 11:37:05,263 StreamSession.java (line 218) [Stream #fc3f4290-26f7-11e5-9988-afe392008597] Starting streaming to /192.168.1.101
     INFO [StreamConnectionEstablisher:1] 2015-07-10 11:37:05,274 StreamResultFuture.java (line 173) [Stream #fc3f4290-26f7-11e5-9988-afe392008597] Prepare completed. Receiving 0 files(0 bytes), sending 112 fi
    les(6538607891 bytes)
    ERROR [STREAM-IN-/192.168.1.101] 2015-07-10 11:37:05,303 StreamSession.java (line 467) [Stream #fc3f4290-26f7-11e5-9988-afe392008597] Streaming error occurred
    java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:384)
            at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:51)
            at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:239)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/192.168.1.101] 2015-07-10 11:37:05,312 StreamSession.java (line 467) [Stream #fc3f4290-26f7-11e5-9988-afe392008597] Streaming error occurred
    java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDi
```

### Questions

Q1. Is it normal for Cassandra 2.0.15 to not bootstrap into 1.2.19 cluster as it was in eperiment 1? (Here I mean that it might not supposed to work by design)
Q2. Is move token operation supposed to work for Cassandra 2.0.15 node which operates in 1.2.19 cluster?
Q3. Are there any workarounds/recommendations of doing a proper rolling upgrade in our case?